# How do I declare an array created using malloc to be volatile in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, arrays, malloc, volatile

I presume that the following will give me 10 volatile ints

```
volatile int foo[10];
```

However, I don't think the following will do the same thing.

```
volatile int* foo;
foo = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

Please correct me if I am wrong about this and how I can have a volatile array of items using malloc.

Thanks.

Comment: I found a good explanation here:
 http://www.embedded.com/story/OEG20010615S0107

Comment: I've started a usenet question on this: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/4af91d60c2a1af8a?pli=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int volatile * foo;
```

read from right to left "foo is a pointer to a volatile int"

so whatever int you access through foo, the int will be volatile.

P.S.

```
int * volatile foo; // "foo is a volatile pointer to an int"
```

!=

```
volatile int * foo; // foo is a pointer to an int, volatile
```

Meaning foo is volatile.  The second case is really just a leftover of the general right-to-left rule.
The lesson to be learned is get in the habit of using

```
char const * foo;
```

instead of the more common

```
const char * foo;
```

If you want more complicated things like "pointer to function returning pointer to int" to make any sense.

P.S., and this is a biggy (and the main reason I'm adding an answer):

I note that you included "multithreading" as a tag.  Do you realize that volatile does little/nothing of good with respect to multithreading?

Comment: volatile must be used when sharing state variables between threads; particularly for concurrent lock free algorithms where you use busy waits. E.g. thread 1 will spin on this instruction: while(barrier); until thread 2 sets barrier=false. If volatile was not used, then code could be deadlocked if the compiler decided to read the barrier value from it's local register instead of memory.

Comment: No - volatile does not insert a memory barrier for all compilers. See http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/

Comment: yes, there is the rare case where volatile does some good.
But a spin lock requires a memory barrier, or at least the data being read after 'barrier == true' needs a memory barrier.

On MSVC volatile implies barriers, but that's non-standard.

Comment: I like the observation about how to write qualifiers into declerations.  Going to start using it.

Comment: Do you mean `!=` instead of `==`? I think `volatile int * foo;` has the same meaning as `int volatile * foo;`

Comment: Volatile means that the value MUST be read from main memory.  While this does not insert a Barrier, current hardware MUST use a barrier to  manage cache.  This is how HW overcomes false sharing.  So while the compiler may not be required to insert a memory barrier, you are in fact insisting on one being present by using the volatile keyword.

Comment: yep, meant !=.  Wow, only 10 years late. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

```
volatile int* foo;
```

is the way to go. The **volatile** type qualifier works just like the **const** type qualifier. If you wanted a pointer to a constant array of integer you would write:

```
const int* foo;
```

whereas

```
int* const foo;
```

is a constant pointer to an integer that can itself be changed. **volatile** works the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that will work. There is nothing different about the actual memory that is `volatile`. It is just a way to tell the compiler how to interact with that memory.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've started a question on usenet about it: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/4af91d60c2a1af8a?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

I think the second declares the pointer to be volatile, not what it points to.  To get that, I think it should be

```
int * volatile foo;
```

This syntax is acceptable to `gcc`, but I'm having trouble [convincing myself](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html) that it does anything different.

I found a difference with `gcc -O3` (full optimization).  For this (silly) test code:

```
volatile int  v [10];
int * volatile p;

int main (void)
{
        v [3] = p [2];
        p [3] = v [2];
        return 0;
}
```

With `volatile`, and omitting (x86) instructions which don't change:

```
    movl    p, %eax
    movl    8(%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, v+12
    movl    p, %edx
    movl    v+8, %eax
    movl    %eax, 12(%edx)
```

Without volatile, it skips reloading `p`:

```
    movl    p, %eax
    movl    8(%eax), %edx    ; different since p being preserved
    movl    %edx, v+12
    ; 'p' not reloaded here
    movl    v+8, %edx
    movl    %edx, 12(%eax)   ; p reused
```

After many more science experiments trying to find a difference, I conclude there is no difference.  `volatile` turns off all optimizations related to the variable which would reuse a subsequently set value.  At least with x86 gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20070925 (Red Hat 4.1.2-33).  :-)

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way around? with volatile, it should force the reload of p.

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug, actually. With volatile, it has to do two reads from `p`, because the Standard says there are two reads (lvalue to rvalue conversions).

Comment: Yep.  I had it backwards.  It's now fixed.

Comment: +1, proof behind your statements. :) Good to see assembly occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much to wallyk, I was able to devise some code use his method to generate some assembly to prove to myself the difference between the different pointer methods.

using the code: and compiling with -03

```
int main (void)
{
        while(p[2]);
        return 0;
}
```

when p is simply declared as pointer, we get stuck in a loop that is impossible to get out of. Note that if this were a multithreaded program and a different thread wrote p[2] = 0, then the program would break out of the while loop and terminate normally.

```
int * p;
============
LCFI1:
        movq    _p(%rip), %rax  
        movl    8(%rax), %eax   
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jne     L6              
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        leave
        ret
L6:
        jmp     L6
```

notice that the only instruction for L6 is to goto L6.

## ==

when p is volatile pointer

```
int * volatile p;
==============
L3:
        movq    _p(%rip), %rax
        movl    8(%rax), %eax
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jne     L3
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

here, the pointer p gets reloaded each loop iteration and as a consequence the array item also gets reloaded. However, this would not be correct if we wanted an array of volatile integers as this would be possible:

```
int* volatile p;
..
..
int* j;
j = &p[2];
while(j);
```

and would result in the loop that would be impossible to terminate in a multithreaded program.

## ==

finally, this is the correct solution as tony nicely explained.

```
int volatile * p;
LCFI1:
        movq    _p(%rip), %rdx
        addq    $8, %rdx
        .align 4,0x90
L3:
        movl    (%rdx), %eax
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jne     L3
        leave
        ret
```

In this case the the address of p[2] is kept in register value and not loaded from memory, but the value of p[2] is reloaded from memory on every loop cycle.

also note that

```
int volatile * p;
..
..
int* j;
j = &p[2];
while(j);
```

will generate a compile error.